# Dreamweaver: Overlaying an image so it makes it easier to adjust CSS and positioning items?

Tags: css, photoshop, dreamweaver

I have a website i have created in Photoshop, i am exported everything i need. I now need to set things up in dreamweaver and position thing using CSS.

I want to ensure that i align my items in HTML exactly how they are in the PSD.

Does dreamweaver support Alpha overlays or something similar ?

Comment: Even if it did you can't be sure that the browser built into Dreamweaver would display the page like any other "real" browser. You certainly can't be sure all browsers will display things the same way either.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most effective ways to do it is to preview changes in Firefox and use the Pixel Perfect extension.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/

You might want to use a good CSS reset, to minimize browser inconsistencies.

If you don't want to install the extension, an alternative is to create an almost transparent png image in Photoshop and overlay it over the html. Use it while you are aligning the html elements with HTML and CSS and remove it once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a place to do this right in DW. Modify>Page Properties> tracing image
you will be able to adjust the transparency of the image here.
check my screenshot [image: screenshot].

But , the other answer here has a good point, that for web development, it's really best design and test repeatedly in the browsers since they all render slightly different.